# How to use <force:previewPanel aura:id="previewPanel"/> in aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, js

I am getting this error while using this code in aura compopnent
Error:Failed to save ObjAttachment.cmp: No COMPONENT named force:previewPanel found: Source

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Components not listed in the [Web Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) are not accessible to developers. You haven't provided a lot of details, so I'm not sure how to help further, but this line of thinking is a dead-end.